# Getting specific date format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the data format below to another form.

here is the `date` I'm getting

```
var datetime =Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:06 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

How can i get `date` in this format `03-10-2013 13:41 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write a short function that splits the date string up. Then you can stick them back together in whatever order you like.

Here's a quick example:

```
function tidyDate(theDate) {
    // split up the string into parts separated by colons or whitespace
    var parts = theDate.toString().split(/[:\s]+/);
    // Get the number of the month - Don't forget that it's zero-indexed
    var month = theDate.getMonth() + 1;
    // Let's say that it's morning
    var AMPM = " AM";
    // But we should check whether it's after noon
    if (parseInt(parts[4]) >= 12){
        AMPM = " PM";
    }
    return parts[2] + "-" +  month + "-" + parts[3] + " " + parts[4] + ":" + parts[5] + AMPM;
}    
tidyDate(new Date());
```

returns:

```
03-10-2013 13:41 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you see there is JS's verbose version used when a date is converted to a string. If you would like to specify a format yourself you would need to break down the parts of the date and concatenate them together using the various date methods, eg `date.getYear() + '/' + date.getMonth()` etc.

Alternatively, you can use a library such as [date.js](http://datejs.com) which will do this for you, eg:

```
myDate.toString("dd-mm-yyyy")
```

[Further reading on toString in date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in **pure JS**, then you have to do something like

```
var ms = new Date("Thu Oct 03 2013 13:41:06 GMT+0530 (IST)");
var curr_date = (ms.getDate()< 10) ? "0" + ms.getDate() : ms.getDate();
var curr_month = (ms.getMonth()< 9) ? "0" + (ms.getMonth()+1) : ms.getMonth()+1;
var curr_year = ms.getFullYear();
var hours = ms.getHours();
var min = ms.getMinutes();
suf = (hours >= 12)? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
alert(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + "  " + hours + ":" + min + " " + suf);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iyePAdu/2/)

To be simple, you can try using the following library

### [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY, h:mm a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function dateFormat()
{
    var d = new Date();
    date = d.getDate();
    date = date < 10 ? "0"+date : date;
    mon = d.getMonth()+1;
    mon = mon < 10 ? "0"+mon : mon;
    year = d.getFullYear()
    return (date+"/"+mon+"/"+year);
}
```

and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Posted that would help ur cause exactly..http://jsbin.com/OCikUZO/1/edit

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
  alert('hi');
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());

    var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var hours = date.getHours();

    newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

    return newDate;   
}

var datetime = new Date("January 02, 2012 22:00:00 GMT+0530");
var date = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date(datetime));
var now = date.toLocaleString();
```